# Override Field Association many-to-one doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, overriding, associations

I have a problem overwriting the field in vendor. The field is many-to-one and I need to add a configuration to it
. Nowhere do I see the possibility of adding such a thing. Is anyone able to help?

in vendor I have field

```
        <many-to-one field="order" target-entity="Bundle\Component\Order\Model\Order" inversed-by="items">
            <join-column name="order_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" on-delete="CASCADE" />
       </many-to-one>
```

In this field i need add like this :

```
       <many-to-one field="order" target-entity="Bundle\Component\Order\Model\Order" inversed-by="items">
            <cascade>
                <cascade-persist />
            </cascade>
            <join-column name="order_id" referenced-column-name="id" nullable="false" on-delete="CASCADE" />
       </many-to-one>
```

How can I do that used "association-overrides" ?